How to print Java application context-root in Apache access logs?
How to print Java application context-root in Apache access logs ?
Which format string provides the application context-root ?
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats
Thank you
trying to fix security vulnerability by setting cookie path attribute with the value as actual "context-root" of the java application (in a multi ear/war setup)
